# Secure query using implode with array

Tags: php, arrays, security, pdo

I'm using PDO, and my `$_POST['arraywithdata']` is an array filed with **numeric** values. I think that this is not enough secure, I just wan't to be sure and prevent myself from a hack.

This is my code:

```
$arr = $_POST['arraywithdata'];
$SQL->query("UPDATE `data_s` SET `set` = 1 WHERE `id` IN " . implode(", ", $arr));
```

As you can see, I'm not checking if the post code in a int or something.

Should I rather use something like:

```
implode(", ", (int) $arr)
```

?

I guess the above will not work, since array can not be an integer.

Comment: Good point - this is indeed not secure. I think you'll need to walk through each value individually and make sure it's an int, or escape them. `(int)$arr` will not work - it will break the array.

Comment: You might try using placeholders to do this.

Comment: Note that the [`IN` operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) requires parentheses.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to convert each value of the array and not the array itself. You can use [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map) to do so:

```
implode(", ", array_map('intval', $arr))
```

Here `array_map` will apply [`intval`](http://php.net/intval) to each value of `$arr` and return a new array with the return values.

But as you’re using PDO, you might also be interested in a [PDO solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/php-pdo-can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition).

Comment: +1 but with the side-effect that non-numeric arguments will be turned into `0`.

Comment: @Pekka That’s true. But in general, the sequence of numeric IDs starts with 1.

Comment: @Pekka , yes, but before executing the above query I'll check, if the argument exist in the database.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a bit of a messy way to pass an array to your script, if I were you I'd do the following:

```
<input name="test[]" value="arrayitem1" type="text" />
<input name="test[]" value="arrayitem2" type="text" />
```

Then in the PHP you can either loop through the data using a foreach look and checking `is_int` or use `array_map` with `intval` and then `explode` the data.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, i faced this problem
Here is what i did Hope this help

```
$arr = array(20,40,50);
$query[] = "UPDATE `data_s` SET `set` = 1 WHERE `id` IN (";
$count = count($arr);
foreach($arr as $v)
{
   $query[] = (int)$v;
   if ($count > 1)
    {
      $sql[] =",";
    }
   $count--;
}

$query[] = ")";
$query = implode("\n", $query);

$SQL->query($query);
```

IT will give you query like this
`"UPDATE`data_s`SET`set`= 1 WHERE`id`IN (20,40,50)"`;